# What are the E tags in vim help?

Tags: help-system, tags

I've been browsing vim's help and noticed there are some topics which have multiple `E###` tags and others with just a single `E###` tag. I'm curious as to what the significance of these `E###` tags are. My initial thoughts were they could be "Edits" or "Errors" but I couldn't find any definitive answer in my research.

I found the vim help tags file https://vimhelp.org/tags.html but that didn't help me come up with a conclusion on what these tags are. It was strange that `E` was used but `E[1-9]` were not.

For example:

`:fu` `:function` `E128` `E129` `E123` are all tags for one topic

`:topleft` `E442` only has a single `E###` tag

Comment: I just realize that I didn't completely understood your question so my answer might not be what you asked. I don't understand what you are talking about with the help topics having a single `E`, the only one I can find is the one for the motion `E` [`:h E`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#E), the other ones with digits after the `E` are definitely error codes.

Comment: The vim help tags say there is a `E` tag that maps to `motions.txt` but I guess you can't invoke it with `:help E`.

Comment: Why couldn't you? Try it yourself `:help E` opens [this help page](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#E)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misunderstood. I made the wrong connection seeing the tags in the format of `E motion.txt \E` I thought `E` was mapped to the top of `motion.txt` not specifically the `E` motion key within the `motion.txt` file. I was still expecting `E` with no numbers to be a error code tag. Seems error codes/tags start at E10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help topics of the form `Exxx` where `x` are digits are simply errors. You can have a look at [`:h errors`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/message.txt.html#errors) to see the different error messages.

When such a tag appears next to an "regular" tag it just indicates that the error is related to this topic. This way if you ever get:

```
E128: Function name must start with a capital
```

You can use [`:h E128`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#E128) to get to the doc related to functions.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. They are error codes. After some more digging under `:help 02.8` there is a section near the bottom that specifically explains that `Exxx` are error IDs. It was strange to see multiple on a single topic, and that made me think there was a different meaning to them.